# Error when connecting to postgres using npgsql

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

I'm working on test code to connect to PostgreSQL using npgsql library this is code sample:

```
Dim conn As Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection = New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Fox;User Id=postgres;")
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand
    cmd = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand("select userName from users where id = 1")
    'etc
```

when running my code an exception is raised (in line conn.open() ):

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Npgsql.dll
>
> Additional information: String reference not set to an instance of a String.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you please include the Npgsql version you're using and the full stack trace? From your connection string it seems you might be missing a password.

Comment: @ShayRojansky I'm using version 3.0.4
yesterday I've tried to use null value for password field (or just missing) now I just added the admin password and the code worked perfectly in VB and even in C#. Thank you so much!